# show pop-up message in front of SaveAs dialog

Tags: c++, windows, dialog, save

In Windows application, is it possible to show a popup message in front of SaveAs dialog after SaveAs dialog is being opened? All I managed to get is that popup shows after dialog is closed.

I need to edit an old application written in C++ (I am not author) but can't manage this task. This is part of code:

/* ---- called to display the save file dialog ---- */

```
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd; 
ofn.lpstrFile = lpstrFileName; 
ofn.lpstrTitle = lpstrTitleName;

res = GetSaveFileNameW( &ofn );

/* ---- fix file extension ---- */

MessageBox(NULL, "Test", "Testing", MB_OK);
```

Thanks,
Ilija

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correct, you want check some stuff (for example, file extension) before closing dialog and show message withou closing. If it's so please look at OFN_ENABLEHOOK flag in [OPENFILENAME Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646839%28VS.85%29.aspx). In this case your code will look something like

```
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd; 
ofn.lpstrFile = lpstrFileName; 
ofn.lpstrTitle = lpstrTitleName;

/* enables the hook function */
ofn.Flags |= OFN_ENABLEHOOK;
ofn.ofn.lpfnHook = (LPOFNHOOKPROC) MyHookProc;

/* some code here */

res = GetSaveFileNameW( &ofn );
```

Code for `MyHookProc` will look like this:

```
static UINT CALLBACK MyHookProc( HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_NOTIFY) {
        OFNOTIFYW *notify = (OFNOTIFYW *) lParam;

        if (notify->hdr.code == CDN_FILEOK) {
            /* your code here */
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: No, I just want to show some information message after opening SaveAs dialog, for example: "This file will take a lot of memory" :) Thanks!

Comment: Just handle WM_INITDIALOG in MyHookProc in this case.

Comment: hmm, i tried this but it only opened Save dialog which is similar to one from Win98 :)

Comment: on vista and later you need to use the common file item interface IFileDialog and associates in order to achieve this.

Comment: Did you set OFN_EXPLORER flag in OPENFILENAME? If not you need to set it to get new style of dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can but it would be quite a hack. You would have to create the FileDialog and open it modeless rather than modal, and hidden. So the window is there but you can't see it. When you click your "popup" you can then could unhide the windows dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to extend the GUI of a save file dialog box. You can extend the GUI by using your own dialog resource template, and specify `OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE`. This is how many apps show previews / metadata of documents.